# How to comment a post and get everyone notified?

Tags: support

I know about the use of **@** to get a user notified of a comment, but, is there a way of notifying all the users that have commented the same post?

Comment: There is no way to do that, no. Single user notify only.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: And how are we supposed to test the _massive_ comments?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Thanks, but wouldn't it be useful?

Comment: I'd rather it didn't exist, myself. Too much potential for excessive noise.  Why do you think it *should* exist?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Actually I needed it. I was sharing comments on an answer and needed to say the same to 2 users. I could notified one, but if the other never gets to read my comment I may never see his point of view, which I think is one of the greatest things of SO, the _"points of view sharing"_ ;)

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Spamming comments into my inbox? No thank you.

Comment: If this is implemented, I'll probably quit SE. Nothing wrong with the feature, but I'm not interested in contributing to a social network or a discussion forum. I'm here to ask and answer questions, not exchange or share points of view.

Comment: @e.campver in case of real need, simply write comment to the first user then `@reply` to the other saying "see my comment to [other name here]".

Comment: Curiosity took over: if you want to notify anybody, you need a comment voor any user. And because you can only @user one user per comment, and you can only have one comment per 5 seconds, it will take you roughly 250 days to do that.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe he clearly said "notifying all the users **that have commented the same post**". Hard to believe all Stack Overflow users will comment on a single post. This is innocent question of one who is not familiar with the system, no idea why so much hostility from so many people here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd how is that hostile, I just wanted to calculate the number if you want to notify all.

Comment: @Toon he meant all users commenting on a certain post. You gave answer as though he asked how to send notification to all users that ever existed. In my eyes that's sarcasm, sorry if I misunderstood your real intention here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd no problem.